# CTP 5 EF Code First UpdateModel()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now and I'm still not able to figure it out.  I've created a sample project to hopefully help figure this issue out.  The main issue is when I load a user from my context and perform an UpdateModel() on this object it seems to delete my entity references and I get null references in child objects.

Here is the error:

> The operation failed: The relationship
> could not be changed because one or
> more of the foreign-key properties is
> non-nullable. When a change is made to
> a relationship, the related
> foreign-key property is set to a null
> value. If the foreign-key does not
> support null values, a new
> relationship must be defined, the
> foreign-key property must be assigned
> another non-null value, or the
> unrelated object must be deleted

.

Here is the link to the code:
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/contactsctp5/source/browse/Contacts/Contacts/Controllers/ContactsController.cs) (line 42, causes the error to happen)

Comment: What would you suggest when I'm updating a collection of child objects?

Comment: do it manually first, after you might look for a way to make it generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this question out thanks to Morteza Manavi on the entity framework website.  My issue was caused by my ContactInformation model properties, 'contactid' & 'contacttypeid' not being nullable.  Once I fixed this everything with UpdateModel() worked correctly.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any data annotations on your key values like [Required] or [StringLength], that would explain the error message.

Comment: No, nothing like that yet.  I've removed all data annotations including key and I still get this error.  I've updated the google code site to reflect this: http://code.google.com/p/contactsctp5/source/browse/Contacts/Contacts/Controllers/ContactsController.cs